# Inject HTML to a Mailgun template variable

Tags: html, node.js, templates, mailgun

I have created a `main` template in Mailgun, with a `{{body}}` variable within the HTML code.

Sending emails using this template works fine when passing a simple string to the `body` variable, but I would like to be able to pass some HTML. Something like that:

```
    return mailgun.messages().send({
        from: fromEmail,
        to: toEmail,
        subject: subject,
        template: "main",
        "v:body": "<p>This is a <strong>parsed</strong> HTML paragraph.</p>",
    }, (error, body) => {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

The email gets sent but the `body` HTML is not rendered and appears as full text in the email (as in showing the tags).

Is there a way to inject HTML so that it is actually rendered?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since Mailgun [uses Handlebars templates by default](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#templating), you could use the "triple-stash" syntax [`{{{body}}}`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping) instead of `{{body}}` to prevent Handlebars from escaping the HTML.

Comment: Had the same question. This answer worked for me as well. Mailgun should really include this in their template documentation.

Comment: Also working with php & mailgun